# Intermolecular interaction between aniline and dichloromethane

Tags: organic-chemistry, intermolecular-forces

**Short background**

As it is known there are interactions between:

1. Charges
2. Charge and dipole
3. Hydrogen bonding
4. van der Waals (VDW) forces

From stronger (1) to weaker (4).

[VDW forces](https://chem.libretexts.org/Core/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry/Physical_Properties_of_Matter/Atomic_and_Molecular_Properties/Intermolecular_Forces/Specific_Interactions/Van_Der_Waals_Interactions) are divided into dipole-dipole, dipole-induced dipole, induced-induced dipole; also from stronger to weaker.

**The problem**

Reading about solutions I found interesting the intermolecular forces involved on aniline and dichloromethane mixing. Below both structrures are shown:

[image: ![aniline]**Aniline** 
[image: ![dichloromethane] **Dichloromethane**

**Question**

What is the most important intermolecular force between those molecules and why? It might be interesting to see an AIM analysis of aniline, but I have no idea how to do that. Also, I'm not sure about what experiment could give valuable information on this case.

**My attempt**

Those previous interactions aren't mutually exclusive. $\ce{-NH2}$ might be a negative density region of the molecule (inductive attraction), but it is also donor by resonance, so the ring has partially a negative charge density. In consecuence, it is not easy to see the dipole. Dichloromethane, on the contrary, is an easy-to-see dipole.

It might result that London dispersion is the most relevant interaction here, but I can't very well justify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/NSRDS/nbsnsrds10.pdf) NIST publication (caution: link leads directly to a biggish PDF file) the dipole moment in the gas phase of dichloromethane and aniline are quite similar (1.6 and 1.5 D respectively).  These are respectable dipole moments, and neither molecule is very big, so offhand I would say an argument can be made that the dipole-dipole interaction is most important, particularly because it's orienting.

Note by the way that rating dispersion forces as the weakest should be done cautiously. It works for *small* molecules, but since dispersion forces scale with the number of electrons in a molecule and no other interaction does, once you get above a fairly modest size of molecule dispersion forces (along with excluded volume forces) dominate.  That's why eicosane is a solid at room temperature while water is a liquid.

Comment: Very interesting, do you find it easy to see the dipole direction on aniline? I'm in trouble with that...

Comment: Nope.  That's why I looked it up.  For what it's worth, I could *rationalize* it by arguing that the entire C6-N system has some pi delocalization going on because it lowers the energy of the pi electrons, to be able to spread out over all 7 atoms.  But that would necessarily mean the N has a partial + and the ring a partial - because the lp is not *always* on the N, roughly speaking.  Hence, a dipole.  But that's all ex post facto hand waving.  One would have to do a quantum chemistry calculation to know whether it checks out.

Comment: From a VB point of view it would suggest a contribution from the resonance structure with NH2+ on one end (with a double bond to C1) and a carbanion at the para position of the ring.  My o-chem is rusty, but isn't that res str the reason NH2 is para (as well as ortho) directing for electrophilic substitution?

Comment: Cool, thanks :) What is VB? Yes you are right with substtutions, that could be seen in some calculations also, I suppose. So the dipole is possibly positive on N and negative on para... interesting.

Comment: Sorry, VB = "valence bond theory, " I mean if you are trying to explain the electronic structure by some combination of Lewis structures.